# Web App accessing data from private sheet

Tags: web, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webapp2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpmld.png)
I have created a webpage (using HTML, CSS and javascript). I have a google sheet that stores data. I want to fetch data from google sheet to this web page and wants to display that. I am able to this task if the google sheet is public. But I don't know how to do it if the google sheet is private. I have attached an image as well which displays the error when we try to fetch data from a private sheet.

This is a google script part.

```js
function doGet() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getValues();
  const headers = data.shift();

  const jsonArray = data.map(r => {
    
    let obj = {};
    headers.forEach((h, i) => {
      obj[h] = r[i];
    })
    return obj;
  });

  const response = [{status: 200, data: jsonArray}];

  return sendJSON(response);
}
```

This is a javascript part.

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="button">Fetch</button>

<script>
 async function testGS() {
   const url="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzn5SQrQDY6gIPfVrsYI4Vy4nPf9O_7Omr_-ehgBv0SabSYSGrbzGGpJZRD7iAkTxfF/exec"
   await fetch(url)
    .then(d => d.json())
    .then(d => {
      console.log(d);
    });
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", 
function() {
  testGS();
});
  </script>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have 2 questions in your question. 1. In your situation, is the owner of the Google Apps Script project of deploying Web Apps the same with the owner of `a private sheet` you want to use? 2. Can I ask you about the settings of your Web Apps for `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`?

Comment: 1. No, the owner of the google apps script project is me, and owner of private sheets is some other person. 2. I don't know, what settings should I keep to implement this, for public sheets, I was using Execute as: me, Who has access to the app: everyone with link. Would be really grateful If you can provide some info on this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your 2nd answer. About `No, the owner of the google apps script project is me, and owner of private sheets is some other person.`, using your Web Apps, you want to read and write the other user's Google Spreadsheet which is not publicly shared. If my understanding correct, in this case, when the Spreadsheet is shared with you, your goal can be achieved. Because the other user's Spreadsheet cannot be directly managed.

Comment: So what's the solution for this, Only allowed users can fetch data from the sheet to the web app and through app's interface can make the changes back into the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about your current script of your Web Apps from your question, in that case, each user directly accesses to the Web Apps using own browser? And from `using the fetch method on the client-side using javascript`, in this case, can you add the script of Google Apps Script side and HTML&Javascript side?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code. can you please check. thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. In your Google Apps Script, `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is used. In this case, the Spreadsheet is your Spreadsheet? I cannot understand about the difference between this situation and `No, the owner of the google apps script project is me, and owner of private sheets is some other person.`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Yes, currently the sheet is public and that is why I can use this method by going to that sheet and using Tools -> Script Editor. Problem is with javascript part, when sheet is private, using project data() function, it displays error in browser console.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when you want to make users access to your Web Apps (deployed with `Execute as: User accessing the web app` and `Who has access: Anyone with Google account`) as each user using `fetch` of Javascript, it is required to share your Google Apps Script project with each user and the access token of each user is required to be used. It seems that this is the current specification. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: If you don't want to share your Google Apps Script project with each user, in that case, how about directly accessing to Web Apps using each browser? By this, it is not required to share the GAS project with each user and the access token is not required to be used.

Comment: I have added an image url which shows the error I get when I try to run javascript code on the browser. please check.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from the information of your current question, I cannot understand about your current situation and your current issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you add the detail information for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current situation from your updated question. I apologize for this. I cannot understand about the settings of your Web Apps. Can I ask you about the settings of your Web Apps for `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And you are using your script in your question and such error occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Execute as: User accesing web app, Who has access to the app: anyone with google account

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your current setting of your Web Apps. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about my 2nd question for your situation of `And you are using your script in your question and such error occurs. Is my understanding correct?`.

Comment: forget about everything. Please just look at the main question and tell me can we do that? can we fetch data from a private google sheet? If yes, how can we do that? We fetch data from a private google sheet and display it on a browser as a web page. If you don't get it, you can ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You are using your script shown in your question and such error occurs. Is my understanding correct? In this case, it is required to know your current whole script for replicating your issue.

Comment: there is html button. When we click that data should be fetched from google sheet and it should be displayed on the browser's console. It runs smoothly when sheet is public. But shows the error for the private sheet. Now can you please tell how to proceed for private sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. If you are using the script shown in your updated question, in your setting of Web Apps, it is required to share the Spreadsheet with user and use the access token as I have already mentioned at my previous comments [comment1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481162/web-app-accessing-data-from-private-sheet#comment119275391_67481162) and [comment2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481162/web-app-accessing-data-from-private-sheet#comment119275393_67481162) So, can you confirm it again?

Comment: apologies but I dont know about access tokens and how to use it.

Comment: And also, it is required to share your Google Apps Script with each user.

Comment: About `apologies but I dont know about access tokens and how to use it.`, in this case, I think [comment2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481162/web-app-accessing-data-from-private-sheet#comment119275393_67481162) might be useful.

Comment: I just want it to work somehow, I don't have any problem if I have to share google apps script with each user.

Comment: I don't understand what it means from your comment2. Can you please tell quick steps how to solve this.

Comment: If you want to use the access token, I think that Oauth2 and service account can be used. But in this case, I think that the script will be a bit complicate. Because at first, it is required to make users login to Google account. So, I think that when users directly access to your Web Apps instead of `fetch`, the script will be simpler. Because the access token is not required to be used.

Comment: About `I don't understand what it means from your comment2. Can you please tell quick steps how to solve this.`, this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: By the way, in your Google Apps Script, `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is used. In this case, the Spreadsheet is your Spreadsheet? I think that if the owner of Spreadsheet is not you, where this script is put to? I cannot understand about your current situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: We can access the spreadsheet by using the spreadsheet Id as well. so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and its comments I understand that you developed a web-app that fetches data from a Sheet. Anybody can run the web-app, and it access the data as the user accessing the web-app. Furthermore the Sheet is owned by a different user to keep it private. In that case, you can't access the Sheet with your web-app because the Sheet is private. I strongly recommend you to ask the Sheet owner to change it status in one of the following ways:

1. Update the Sheet from private to public.
2. Share the Sheet with you and update the web-app to access the data as your account.

Please write back in this answer if you need help configuring one of the workarounds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. We can not use a public sheets since it contains confidential data. Even I'm not allowed to use that sheet because I am intern at the firm. They have asked me to build web application, which will be used by particular users. So is there any way?

Comment: Thank you for your acknowledgement. I strongly recommend you to ask new questions in a separate question, in order to receive appropriate help and keep it clear.